# can a model outperform on test data then on training data

Tags: neural-networks, variance, bias

I am training Deep Neural Networks  on a classification problem. N while choosing the no of epochs, I get below graph :
[image]

So my question is that this case neither comes in high bias and nor in high variance. 
The error rate of training set is high then the test set. Is that even possible?

And what do we infer from this graph (like how we would have done for the reverse case ) in terms of bias and variance?

Comment: How big is the validation set in comparison to the training set?

Comment: underfitting sometimes happens

Comment: @sycorax-says-reinstate-monica would we expect underfitting to lead to better performance on the holdout data?

Comment: Were your train and test sets sampled randomly from the same population? What you see is definitely possible but it's abnormal under standard conditions.

Comment: I have around 500 samples which is definately  less. Out of these, i am holding 80 percent for training set

Comment: I assume that this is more likely to happen if you are using regularization techniques. For instance, by using drop out, adding jitter, and so on.

Comment: If this is a classification problem - are you using stratified random sampling to determine the holdout? Since you have small data have you confirmed whether the class distribution of the holdout is similar to the training data?

Comment: I am using regularilization techniques of drop out, and also I am using LOOCV as I have small data set